# What is the 10.42.0.1 address in my k3s cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, k3s

I'm trying to figure out what the address 10.42.0.1 is resolving to ( or what it belongs to ).  I have a very basic k3s cluster with all the defaults enabled ( so the default pod cidr is 10.42.0.0/24 I think ).  None of my pods in the cluster are indicating they own that address.  When I curl the address from a pod in side of my cluster, it seems to resolve to the traefik deployed load balancer, but I'm trying to figure out the mechanics behind this, mostly for curiosity.

For reference, this is what's currently in the cluster

```
    NAMESPACE      NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS      AGE   IP           NODE         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system    helm-install-traefik-crd-rrt22              0/1     Completed   0             19h   <none>       k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system    helm-install-traefik-lxtmr                  0/1     Completed   1             19h   <none>       k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system    svclb-traefik-9fa171fb-26n2r                2/2     Running     2 (59m ago)   19h   10.42.0.11   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system    traefik-64f55bb67d-5b4nv                    1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   19h   10.42.0.13   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system    coredns-77ccd57875-dg92g                    1/1     Running     1 (59m ago)   19h   10.42.0.10   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system    local-path-provisioner-957fdf8bc-vjrxt      1/1     Running     2 (58m ago)   19h   10.42.0.12   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system    metrics-server-648b5df564-btzmp             1/1     Running     2 (58m ago)   19h   10.42.0.9    k8s-master   <none>           <none>
kube-system    svclb-traefik-9fa171fb-gkktp                2/2     Running     2 (53m ago)   19h   10.42.1.3    k8s-agent    <none>           <none>
istio-system   istiod-5f859db56c-2nsbz                     1/1     Running     0             51m   10.42.1.4    k8s-agent    <none>           <none>
kube-system    svclb-istio-ingressgateway-8b3c00eb-zd5cw   0/3     Pending     0             51m   <none>       <none>       <none>           <none>
kube-system    svclb-istio-ingressgateway-8b3c00eb-cbznb   0/3     Pending     0             51m   <none>       <none>       <none>           <none>
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway-794b8468f5-pbd8z       1/1     Running     0             51m   10.42.0.14   k8s-master   <none>           <none>
default        client-59f4b74cd-sxct5                      2/2     Running     0             19m   10.42.1.6    k8s-agent    <none>           <none>

NAMESPACE      NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP         PORT(S)                                      AGE   SELECTOR
default        kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>              443/TCP                                      19h   <none>
kube-system    kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>              53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP                       19h   k8s-app=kube-dns
kube-system    metrics-server         ClusterIP      10.43.65.157    <none>              443/TCP                                      19h   k8s-app=metrics-server
kube-system    traefik                LoadBalancer   10.43.95.159    10.0.0.4,10.0.0.5   80:31462/TCP,443:31401/TCP                   19h   app.kubernetes.io/instance=traefik-kube-system,app.kubernetes.io/name=traefik
istio-system   istiod                 ClusterIP      10.43.169.1     <none>              15010/TCP,15012/TCP,443/TCP,15014/TCP        51m   app=istiod,istio=pilot
istio-system   istio-ingressgateway   LoadBalancer   10.43.221.192   <pending>           15021:31385/TCP,80:31036/TCP,443:30469/TCP   51m   app=istio-ingressgateway,istio=ingressgateway
default        httpd                  ClusterIP      10.43.254.191   <none>              80/TCP                                       38m   app=httpd
```